# VBA to copy and append filtered data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DS()

    Dim sourceWorkook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long


    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "H:\L\Roy\RT\Transfers\Transfers 2020 - Roy.xlsm"
    targetWorkbookPath = "H:\L\Roy\H and E\2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2.xlsx"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' definr worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("ST TO ST")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sourceSheet

        ' Get last row
        lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"

        .Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B1")
        .Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1")
        .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F1")
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to Append the filtered data under the last (used row) in the target workbook. This code copies data from source to target but I want to append this data to the target workbook since I am using the target workbook for most of the work.

Comment: You will need to find the `lastRow` for each column in the `targetSheet` before you copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Only a few bits you need to add to append data to first empty row:

```
Sub BitsAndPeicesExample()
        
    ' ...   ...   ...

    Dim tLastRow As Long
        
    ' ...   ...   ...
    
    '    Whatever column works > \|/
    tLastRow = targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    '                            /|\
    ' ...   ...   ...
    
    .Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A" & tLastRow)
        
    ' ...   ...   ...

End Sub
```

I would encourage you to consider alternatives to `.copy` such as `[...].value = [...].value`

You might need `.resize` to make source and destination ranges the same size. idk